# OpenVPN stops after a couple of minutes, seems to hang all system networking

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to create an OpenVPN connection. My colleagues using Windows have received a self-extracting executable
that sets up everything, but I could recover the `.ovpn` and key files from their configuration.

The .opvn says:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd 1194 udp
verify-x509-name "Bad_VPN" name
auth-user-pass
pkcs12 SomeKey.p12
tls-auth SomeKey-tls.key 1
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo adaptive
```

With an adequate password, the connection starts and I can ping systems. However, if I start the VPN, 
and immeditley start a `ping` that I leave running:

- after roughly one minute, there are no longer any ping answers (no seq>57)
- after roughly a second minute, I get one last ping answer (one for seq=118) and a message that 'tun0' was deactivated.

Also, while the VPN is up, I can only ping the network it connects to.

While the VPN is up, `ip route` says:

```
default via 192.168.30.1 dev tun0  proto static  metric 50 
default via xxx.143.182.1 dev wlp4s0  proto static  metric 600 
xxx.0.136.31 via xxx.143.182.1 dev wlp4s0  proto dhcp  metric 600 
xxx.143.182.0/23 dev wlp4s0  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.143.182.197  metric 600 
10.101.54.0/24 via 192.168.30.1 dev tun0  proto static  metric 50 
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd via xxx.143.182.1 dev wlp4s0  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.30.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.3  metric 50
```

For comparison, without VPN:

```
default via xxx.143.182.1 dev wlp4s0  proto static  metric 600 
xxx.0.136.31 via xxx.143.182.1 dev wlp4s0  proto dhcp  metric 600 
xxx.143.182.0/23 dev wlp4s0  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.143.182.197  metric 600
```

(`xxx.*.*.*` is my usual network, `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` is the VPN gateway).

`/var/log/syslog` says:

```
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904111.3023] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015" name="ProblemVPN" pid=18679 uid=1000 result="success"
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904111.3124] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 14000
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904111.3289] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[14003] started
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904111.3433] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: Control Channel Authentication: using '/home/me/.local/share/networkmanagement/certificates/SomeKey-tls.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:1194
Jan  2 15:41:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: [Bad_VPN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:1194
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_113 --tun -- tun0 1500 1558 192.168.30.3 255.255.255.0 init
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0624] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/57)
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0688] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0688] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0733] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0752] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0758] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data: VPN Gateway: aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0758] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data: Tunnel Device: "tun0"
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: chroot to '/var/lib/openvpn/chroot' and cd to '/' succeeded
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0759] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data: IPv4 configuration:
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: GID set to nm-openvpn
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0759] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Gateway: 192.168.30.1
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: UID set to nm-openvpn
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0759] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Address: 192.168.30.3
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0759] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Prefix: 24
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0759] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 192.168.30.3
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0759] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0760] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.101.54.0/24   Next Hop: 192.168.30.1
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0760] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   Forbid Default Route: no
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: A new network interface has been detected.
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0760] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data:   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: logInterfaces File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 2105 Invoked Function: logInterfaces Return Code: 0 (0x00000000) Description: IP Address Interface List: xxx.143.163.90 FE80:0:0:0:8F3A:7426:4E4E:ADBC FE80:0:0:0:BE55:25A5:1450:A479
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0760] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: Data: No IPv6 configuration
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0761] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: A new network interface has been detected.
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: logInterfaces File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 2105 Invoked Function: logInterfaces Return Code: 0 (0x00000000) Description: IP Address Interface List: xxx.143.163.90 192.168.30.3 FE80:0:0:0:8F3A:7426:4E4E:ADBC FE80:0:0:0:BE55:25A5:1450:A479
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0790] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) complete
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0792] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0823] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0824] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid dbus[1080]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0857] keyfile: add connection in-memory (e354d75d-c20c-49d7-ab96-8dc25ebc53d2,"tun0")
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0863] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.0891] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (e354d75d-c20c-49d7-ab96-8dc25ebc53d2)
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid kernel: [1062318.614395] IPv4: martian source xxx.143.163.90 from xxx.0.136.50, on dev enp0s31f6
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid kernel: [1062318.614398] ll header: 00000000: c8 5b 76 df 39 d9 0c 85 25 c0 64 c0 08 00        .[v.9...%.d...

[... repeated three times total ...] 

Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid dbus[1080]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1088] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1094] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1097] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1099] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1110] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 xxx. 0]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1113] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1138] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1139] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1139] policy: set 'tun0' (tun0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904114.1140] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid kernel: [1062318.640875] IPv4: martian source xxx.143.163.90 from 54.230.92.116, on dev enp0s31f6
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid kernel: [1062318.640878] ll header: 00000000: c8 5b 76 df 39 d9 0c 85 25 c1 6b 40 08 00        .[v.9...%.k@..
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid org.kde.kdeconnect[18558]: kdeconnect.core: Broadcasting identity packet
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid kernel: [1062318.654094] IPv4: martian source xxx.143.163.90 from xxx.0.136.50, on dev enp0s31f6
Jan  2 15:41:54 Xenoid kernel: [1062318.654096] ll header: 00000000: c8 5b 76 df 39 d9 0c 85 25 c0 64 c0 08 00        .[v.9...%.d...

[... More "martian source" and "ll header" messages ...]

Jan  2 15:41:59 Xenoid kernel: [1062323.619584] net_ratelimit: 14 callbacks suppressed

[... More "martian source" and "ll header" messages ...]

Jan  2 15:42:01 Xenoid org.kde.kdeconnect[18558]: kdeconnect.core: Broadcasting identity packet
Jan  2 15:42:04 Xenoid kernel: [1062328.625257] net_ratelimit: 6 callbacks suppressed

[... More "martian source" and "ll header" messages ...]

Jan  2 15:42:04 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...

[... More "martian source", "ll header", and "net_ratelimit" messages ...]

Jan  2 15:43:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: [Bad_VPN] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Jan  2 15:43:51 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Jan  2 15:43:52 Xenoid kernel: [1062436.606725] IPv4: martian source xxx.143.163.90 from xxx.0.136.50, on dev enp0s31f6
Jan  2 15:43:52 Xenoid kernel: [1062436.606750] ll header: 00000000: c8 5b 76 df 39 d9 0c 85 25 c0 64 c0 08 00        .[v.9...%.d...
Jan  2 15:43:52 Xenoid kernel: [1062436.610871] IPv4: martian source xxx.143.163.90 from xxx.0.138.50, on dev enp0s31f6
Jan  2 15:43:52 Xenoid kernel: [1062436.610894] ll header: 00000000: c8 5b 76 df 39 d9 0c 85 25 c0 64 c0 08 00        .[v.9...%.d...
Jan  2 15:43:53 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Jan  2 15:43:53 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jan  2 15:43:53 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Jan  2 15:43:53 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:1194
Jan  2 15:43:53 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: [Bad_VPN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:1194
Jan  2 15:43:53 Xenoid kernel: [1062438.330281] IPv4: martian source xxx.143.163.90 from xxx.57.61.80, on dev enp0s31f6
Jan  2 15:43:53 Xenoid kernel: [1062438.330286] ll header: 00000000: c8 5b 76 df 39 d9 0c 85 25 c1 6b 40 08 00        .[v.9...%.k@..
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tun0
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_113 --tun -- tun0 1500 1558 192.168.30.3 255.255.255.0 restart
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): could not execute external program
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-openvpn[14003]: Exiting due to fatal error
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: A network interface has gone down.
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: logInterfaces File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 2105 Invoked Function: logInterfaces Return Code: 0 (0x00000000) Description: IP Address Interface List: xxx.143.163.90 FE80:0:0:0:8F3A:7426:4E4E:ADBC
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <error> [1514904235.1882] platform-linux: do-add-ip4-route[24: 0.0.0.0/0 50]: failure 101 (Network is unreachable)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <warn>  [1514904235.1883] default-route: failed to add default route 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.30.1 dev 24 metric 50 mss 0 src vpn with effective metric 50
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.1883] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.1884] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.1885] policy: set 'ProblemVPN' (tun0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.1898] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged') [100 10 3]
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid dbus[1080]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.1956] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid dbus[1080]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: (nm-openvpn-service:14000): nm-openvpn-WARNING **: openvpn[14003] exited with error code 1
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid whoopsie[1562]: [15:43:55] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/113
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <warn>  [1514904235.2272] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.2272] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.2272] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.2278] vpn-connection[0x1c2e630,46cde9dc-b96e-4a27-92f2-980856086015,"ProblemVPN",24:(tun0)]: VPN plugin: state change reason: unknown (0)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.2278] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <info>  [1514904235.2303] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid NetworkManager[1102]: <error> [1514904235.2309] platform-linux: do-change-link[24]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:2 'vpn-down' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid acvpnagent[1851]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Jan  2 15:43:55 Xenoid nm-dispatcher: req:2 'vpn-down' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
```

With the NM gui, I tried to remove the automating routing, but couldn't get a valid configuration that way. I also tries several variants of `ip route del default via 192.168.30.1 dev tun0` but although I didn't see any error messages the route remained.

Any ideas (besides starting a Windows VM...)?

Running (K)ubuntu 16.04

**Update**: OK, I lied:) I also have docker, and removed `docker0` from the `ip route` outputs... And using the NM GUI to disconnect from `docker0` seems to fix the problem. Ran for 20mn and only lost a few packets (10/1261). However, I cannot find any hint that OpenVPN and docker don't like each other.

**Update "2**: The working tests above were from home, on Ethernet via PLC. So it works whith a wire connection to my simple home LAN, but doesn't work with:

- the company's internal network (wifi or ethernet)
- the company's "guests" wifi
- my home wifi
- my phone (as Wifi hostspot)
- my phone (with USB cable)

Comment: OK, I lied:) I also have docker, and removed `docker0` from the `ip route` outputs above... And using the NM GUI to disconnect from `docker0` seems to fix the problem. Ran for 20mn and only lost a few packets (10/1261).

Comment: Something in you NM configuration is setting a default route via the VPN. It's not in the OpenVPN configuration file so it must be in NM. You should remove that and replace it with an appropriate set of network routes

Comment: @roaima The problem is that I can't find anything that does this. Pored over plenty of things in /etc, not that many mentions of "route" there. I could even leave with that routing if that was the only broken thing. The the disconnection after a minute is a bigger worry.

Comment: The issue is with your NM. Disable it and try again.

Comment: I need NM. I switch networks all the time. What is wrong with it?

Comment: using NM on the server side is not a best practice as I understand.  I've too faced lots of issues while using it.... use a command line to switch between networks.

Comment: Although I mentioned docker, this is my laptop we are talking about...